# Can't seem to solve a radical equation? Question is : $\sqrt{x+19} + \sqrt{x-2} = 7$

Tags: radicals

So there is this equation that I've been trying to solve but keep having trouble with.

The unit is about solving Radical equations and the question says
**Solve:**
$$\sqrt{x+19} + \sqrt{x-2} = 7$$

I don't want the answer blurted, I want to know how it's done, including steps please.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint : Square the equation, isolate the square-root term and square again.

Comment: $6$ is the only solution.

Comment: You can check your answer with http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(x%2B19)+%2B+sqrt(x-2)+%3D+7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sqrt{x+19} + \sqrt{x-2} = 7$

Squaring both sides, we have

$x+19+2\sqrt{x+19}\sqrt{x-2}+x-2=49$

Collecting terms, we have

$2x+17+2\sqrt{x^2+17x-38}=49$

$\sqrt{x^2+17x-38}=\dfrac{32-2x}{2}$

Squaring again

$x^2+17x-38=\dfrac{1024-128+4x^2}{4}$

$x^2+17x-38=256-32x+x^2$

$49x=294$

$\therefore x=\dfrac{294}{49}=6$

We can easily verify that this is a correct solution.

Comment: As a comment, I'd imagine it is computationally easier to first divide the $32-2x$ by $2$ to get $16-x$ then square that term, but this is a trivial alteration.

Comment: Very true. I hadn't noticed this when I was first solving it.  Oh well.

Answer (score 10):

Multiply both sides by $\sqrt{x+19} -\sqrt{x-2} $ to get
$$x+19 -(x-2) = 7 (\sqrt{x+19} - \sqrt{x-2}) \\
21 = 7 (\sqrt{x+19} - \sqrt{x-2}) \\
3 =\sqrt{x+19} - \sqrt{x-2}$$

Adding this to the original equation you get
$$2\sqrt{x+19}=10 \Rightarrow x+19=25 \Rightarrow x=6$$

**P.S.** You can find the same method employed in my answer here:
[to this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399199/solve-equations-sqrtt-9-sqrtt-1/399237#399237)

Answer (score 4):

To solve a simple sum of radical equations, you can use with fun and profit the [radical equation calculator](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/radical-equation-calculator/%5Csqrt%7B%5Cleft%5C%7Bx%2B19%5Cright%5C%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B%5Cleft%5C%7Bx-2%5Cright%5C%7D%7D%3D7/?origin=button). It gives you some steps, as describe below:

[image: radical equation calculator]

In your case, a sum of two radicals equating a constant, the "isolate one root and square" method can help:
$$\sqrt{x+19}+\sqrt{x−2}=7\,.$$
So:  isolate, as much as you can, one radical on one side
$$\sqrt{x+19}=7 - \sqrt{x−2}$$
square:
$$x+19 = 49 + x-2-14 \sqrt{x−2}$$
simplify and isolate one radical again
$$28 =14 \sqrt{x−2}$$
$$2=\sqrt{x−2}$$
then square again, and you get $x=6$. Of course, you need to verify that the solution is valid, for instance that it does not involve radicals of negative numbers.

This way, you minimize products of radicals (like $\sqrt{x+19}\sqrt{x−2}$) that are easy traps. This method would work more generally, provided there are solutions, for the generic equation:

$$\sqrt{a_1 x+a_2}+\sqrt{a_3 x+a_4}=a_5$$

which you can try to exercise your style. More references:

- [Steps required for Solving Problems Containing One Square Root](http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat120/notes/radicals/solving/one_sqrt/one_sqrt.html)
- [Steps required for Solving Problems Containing Two Square Roots](http://mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat120/notes/radicals/solving/two_sqrt/two_sqrt.html)
- [How to Solve a Square Root Equation](https://sciencing.com/solve-square-root-equation--2322650.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this acceptable...

$\sqrt{{x}+\mathrm{19}}+\sqrt{{x}−\mathrm{2}}=\mathrm{7} \\ $
$\sqrt{{x}+\mathrm{19}}=\mathrm{7}−\sqrt{{x}−\mathrm{2}} \\ $
${x}+\mathrm{19}=\mathrm{49}−\mathrm{14}\sqrt{{x}−\mathrm{2}}+\left({x}−\mathrm{2}\right) \\ $
$\mathrm{0}=\mathrm{28}−\mathrm{14}\sqrt{{x}−\mathrm{2}} \\ $
$\mathrm{2}=\sqrt{{x}−\mathrm{2}}\Rightarrow\mathrm{4}={x}−\mathrm{2}\Rightarrow{x}=\mathrm{6} \\ $

Comment: Please note that this question is over 5 years old and this answer doesn't add anything that isn't in another answer already.

Comment: Yes I know.., I do it for fun...